# Get d3 v4 zoom and drag working together - simple example

Tags: d3.js

Consider [this code example](https://bl.ocks.org/puzzler10/d98ca2993392609d55a9d4ec9d31cbd3) in d3 version 4.

There's a number of yellow circles overlaid on top of a black background.

I can drag the circles around with my mouse. I can also zoom in and out using the mousewheel, providing my mouse is not over a circle.

There's two problems that I'd like to fix:

- I would like to zoom in when I hit the scroll wheel while I am moused over a circle.
- Drag and drop is incorrect when I am zoomed in or out of the graph - the circles don't follow the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.  [Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/puzzler10/49f13307e818ea9a909ba5adba5b6ed9) the link to the gist with the solution.

How I fixed each problem:

- The zoom problem was fixed by making the zoom handler trigger on the underlying SVG element, not an overlaying rectangle like it was previously.
- The drag problem was fixed by adjusting the drag function to take into account the current level of zooming